# MongoDB : return a list of all subdocument

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, nested

I'm trying to learn Meteor/Mongo, but each time you think to make progress, a "simple thing" seems totally beyond reach...

I have a very simple document :

```
_id   : abcd
field : xyz
subdoc [
  {_id: 123, email: abc, name: abc}
  {_id: 234, email: abc, name: xyz}
  {_id: 853, email: abc, name: pmu}
]
```

And I want to return a list of all my subdocuments.
Put in another word, I'd like to get a list like this one, in my HTML template using "each":

```
  _id: 123    email: abc    name: abc
  _id: 234    email: abc    name: xyz
  _id: 853    email: abc    name: pmu
```

But I'm totally unable to achieve any results with .dot notation..
Any clue?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: what is the query you are working off of?

Comment: Have you tried to print the response body? Or use any print statements?

Comment: `db.collection.findOne({}, { 'subdoc': 1, '_id': 0 })`  or  `db.collection.find({}, { 'subdoc': 1, '_id': 0 })` depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myCollection.find({_id: 'abcd'}).fetch().forEach(function(item) { return item.subdoc; });
```

or even simpler with findOne

```
myCollection.findOne({_id: 'abcd'}).subdoc;
```

**Note:**

In the 2 cases only one document is returned by the `_id` (since _id is unique) you will get the subdoc array.

If you use the first solution and your query returns multiple documents, then you will get an array of Arrays.

If what you want is a flat array from the array of Arrays, you need to flatten that array

with underscore that would be

```
flattened = _.flatten(nestedArray)
```

Comment: With a lot of delay, sorry. It works like a charm... Thanks.
By the way, if I want to retrieve a specific field in my nested document, what's the simplest way of doing it ?

Comment: use array.map(function(item){return item.field})

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer version of MongoDB (4.x), you can use aggregate functionality. So, instead of flattening in JavaScript, you can do this on Database Server itself.

```
myCollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$subdoc"},
    {$project : {
        _id : 0, 
        id : "$subdoc._id", 
        name : "$subdoc.name", 
        email: "$subdoc.email"
       }
     }
])
```